# KAFKA commit issue

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, librdkafka

I am very new to KAFKA broker and as per the requirement producer has to COMMIT messages.(Using librdkafka c/c++ libraries)

So, Firstly in my producer.c i used rd_kafka_commit (rk,NULL,0) but i got below error
RD_KAFKA_RESP_ERR__UNKNOWN_GROUP = -179 (Unknown  client group)

Now I am using this method rd_kafka_commit_transaction() in my producer.c  but getting compilation error below.

undefined reference to `rd_kafka_init_transactions'

Please help me how to proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the transaction management of the Kafka Producer then you have to

- first initiate a new transaction using the method `rd_kafka_init_transactions()`[here](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/librdkafka/html/rdkafka_8h.html#abf3e48791cf53ac2c7e30a17ce896f74) on your producer
- Then you have to call `rd_kafka_begin_transaction()` [here](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/librdkafka/html/rdkafka_8h.html#a3c5338866b641957e9eeeaa9b60f5f9c).
- After that produce a message
- last step should be to commit the transaction using `rd_kafka_commit_transaction()`.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Apart from transactional API do we have any way to commit producer messages?

Comment: I am not sore what is your exact use case but the librdkafka docs explains everything well here https://github.com/confluentinc/librdkafka/blob/master/INTRODUCTION.md#producer-api